# Error "syntax error near unexpected token `('?"

Tags: shell-script, tcsh, csh

#### What's in my terminal

```
bash: settings64.csh: line 35: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: settings64.csh: line 35: `foreach i ( $xlnxInstLocList )'
```

#### Portion of the script

```
set xlnxInstLocList="${xlnxInstLocList} common"
set xlnxInstLocList="${xlnxInstLocList} EDK"
set xlnxInstLocList="${xlnxInstLocList} PlanAhead"
set xlnxInstLocList="${xlnxInstLocList} ISE"
set XIL_SCRIPT_LOC_TMP_UNI=${XIL_SCRIPT_LOC}
foreach i ( $xlnxInstLocList )
```

#### Location of syntactical error at the bottom

```
line 35
foreach i ( $xlnxInstLocList )
```

I'm not a scripter; I'm trying to fix an error in the scripting for my ISE DESIGN SUITE installation. I just need a quick set of code to replace "foreach i ( $xlnxInstLocList )" to perform its intended function. I think it's a Bash script.

Comment: `.csh` more indicates a CSH script, which is so not bash. Maybe run it under `csh` or `tcsh` intead?

Comment: How do I run it in terminal?

Comment: The environment variables are written to settings[32|64].(c)sh at "/opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS". To launch the Xilinx tools, first source the settings script:

Comment: C-shell 64 bit environment...
source /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/settings64.csh

Comment: The people who are voting to close this because it "cannot be reproduced" should be aware that not only _can_ it be reproduced, but it _has been_ reproduced, years ago.  This is not the first nor the only person to have done this.  [Here's someone making the exact same error in 2011](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Installation-and-Licensing/Syntax-error-while-sourcing-settings-csh-in-Xilinx-13-1/td-p/135442), for just one example.

Answer (score 18):

## Follow the actual installation instructions properly!

You buried this in a comment:

> The environment variables are written to settings[32|64].(c)sh at "/opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS". To launch the Xilinx tools, first source the settings script:

C-shell 64 bit environment...
source /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/settings64.csh

This is just part of [a larger set of unofficial instructions](https://gist.github.com/pdp7/d30718d7af40bf01d376), and you did not read the whole thing properly.  They continue on from that to say:

> Shell, Bash shell, Korn Shell 64 bit environment...
> `. /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/settings64.sh`

The actual instructions from Xilinx itself, as given in the "Linux installation" section of the installation guide, say:

> 1. Go to the XILINX installation directory

2. Type either `source settings32.(c)sh` or `source settings64.(c)sh`, as required for your shell.

As is apparent from your question, you are using the Bourne Again shell.  *So you should be sourcing the `.sh` file not the `.csh` file.*  Stop trying to fix the Xilinx script, which doesn't need fixing, and actually *run the right script for your shell* out of the set of scripts for different shells that Xilinx provides.

## Further reading

- "[Linux Installation](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx14_1/iil.pdf#page=6)".  *Xilinx Design Tools: Installation and Licensing Guide*.  version 14.1.  Xilinx.  2012-05-08.  p. 6.

Answer (score 12):

`bash` doesn't have a `foreach`; this script is probably meant to run in `csh` or `tsch`.  If you are invoking the script with `./myscript.csh`, make sure its first line is `#!/bin/csh` (or whatever the full path to that shell is on your system).

Answer (score 2):

It is a `csh` script. Check if it is executable, else execute `chmod u+x settings64.csh` and run it either with `./settings64.csh` or `csh settings.sh`

Comment: I have an I still get the syntax error

Comment: What Operating system are you running it on?